# Good automatic image annotation software?

Tags: images, file-management, automation

I have several thousand photos organized in a quite simple way that works for me. I have kind of projects, then year, and then project title.

But, sometimes, I want to look at photos following a given concept across multiple projects.

Is there a good [automatic image annotation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Automatic_image_annotation) software that can automatically tag all my photos following a given set of heuristics?

Comment: Any OS preference?

Comment: Ideally OSX, but any OS would work for me. Do you have any ideas?

Comment: Sorry, I do not.  I am interested in something similar for Windows.  What type of heuristics do you have in mind (best to update your question with them instead of providing them in the comments, if you choose to reply)?

Comment: If you want to speed up face annotation then [imaglab](https://github.com/NaturalIntelligence/imglab) may help. It works online and can be upgraded to annotate all the faces in all the images in one go. However to annotate all the objects, we can search some API that can be integrated with imglab. Disclaimer : I'm the author of Imglab.